# PHP readfile() returns malfomed file

Tags: php, readfile

since today I have a strange problem with my website - I have an API call which proxies an image on the webserver. Code:

```
<?php
$file = $_GET["id"];

//returns the absolute path to the image
$path = thumb_location($file);

header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($path));

readfile(realpath($path));
?>
```

This worked perfectly fine until earlier today, when suddenly all of the images are broken. When downloading the image the API call returns and comparing it to the source image, this is the result:

```
$ cmp -b --print-bytes original.jpg malformed.jpg 
original.jpg malformed.jpg differ: byte 1, line 1 is 377 ?  12 ^J
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: try uploading aknown good file and testing with that?

Comment: Open both files in a hex editor and see the difference. Most likely there's some whitespace before `<?php` being output, or PHP produces some error message.

Comment: please re-read the question, original.jpg is a known good file on the server.

Comment: @deceze - turns out the malformed file has 0A prepended, when removing that 0A the file becomes valid. Where might this come from?

Comment: You have a new line (line feed, empty line) somewhere before output.

Comment: Thanks to @Ostin and deceze, your input helped ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After @deceze pointed out that I should inspect the files in a hex editor, I discovered that a line feed character was prepended to the output.
This was caused by a newline after the closing `?>` tag of a PHP file I recently added. Removing the newline (or the `?>` tag) fixed the issue.

Thanks for all your help!